# How to make the blur text in textbox in VB.NET 2010?

Tags: vb.net

I want to know how can I make a blur text appear in the text box as an instruction to use, like `"please enter your name"` or something like that, and it disappears when it got focus. However when it lose focus with empty input text, it reappears again.

So, which properties or methods to implement that?

Comment: WPF? Winforms? Asp.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://vbdotnetpower.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/textual-cue-for-textbox-control.html)'s an example of what you need to do.